# Adjust the legend labels in image plot

Tags: r

Normally I provide some sample code for an reproducible example, but in this case it is a bit tricky. But I believe this question can be solved also without a reproduced example.

I have an image plot generated with the following code:

```
col <- c("red", "white", "blue") # set the color palette
image.plot(lon.list[[1]], lat.list[[1]], MK.list3[[6]][[8]], 
           main = paste0("Drought Index Trend \n", names(Index.list[[1]])[1]), 
           col = col,
           xlab = "Longitude [°]",
           ylab = "Latitude [°]",
           legend.lab = "", 
           legend.line = 2.5,
           zlim = c(-1,1))  
plot(sf_object, add = T, border = "Black")
```

The resulting plot is the following:
[image]

I have a problem with the legend labels. Since there are only three values, `-1, 0, 1`, it is sufficient that only these values are displayed at the legend in the middle of each color.

So it should like this (the different colors don't matter):

[image]

Anybody with a hint how to achieve this?

Comment: `axis.args` might be useful. Along the lines of `imagePlot(x, y, z,  col=c("red", "blue", "green"),  axis.args=list(at=1:3+1, labels=1:3))`

Comment: Thank you, through the comment I found the solution: ```axis.args = list(c(-1:1))```.

Comment: Good stuff. It would be good if you could add an answer showing the full code that works -- could be helpful for others.

Comment: Just done!.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comment of user20650, I found the solution. Here is the updated code which does what I want:

```
col <- c("red", "white", "blue") # set the color palette
image.plot(lon.list[[1]], lat.list[[1]], MK.list3[[6]][[8]], 
           main = names(Index.list[[1]])[8], 
           col = col,
           xlab = "",
           ylab = "",
           legend.lab = "", 
           legend.line = 2.5,
           zlim = c(-1,1),
           axis.args = list(c(-1:1))) ### this is the new part ###
plot(sf_object, add = T, border = "Black")
```